# Determining type of algebraic data structure

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, algebraic-data-types

Suppose `data MyAlgebraicType :: Foo Int | Bar Int`. If I have a variable of type `MyAlgebraicType`, how do I determine if it is a `Foo Int` or a `Bar Int`?

Comment: Minor point: don't call `Foo Int` and `Bar Int` types, since they are not. Here, only `MyAlgebraicType` is a type. Usually, we call `Foo` and `Bar` "constructors". More informally, one can ask "how to determine the form of a value in an algebraic (data) type?"

Answer (score 3):

Using `case`:

```
let var = Bar 42 in
case var of
    Foo _ -> putStrLn "It's a Foo!"
    Bar _ -> putStrLn "It's a Bar!"
```

Those `_` can be replaced with a variable name to bind the `Int` that is contained.

You can also use a pattern matching definition (which is more common than `case`):

```
tellMeIt :: MyAlgebraicType -> IO ()
tellMeIt (Foo _) = putStrLn "It's a Foo!"
tellMeIt (Bar _) = putStrLn "It's a Bar!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching is usually better, but in some cases, code can be easier to read using functions like these:

```hs
isFoo :: MyAlgebraicType -> Bool
isFoo (Foo _) = True
isFoo _       = False

isBar :: MyAlgebraicType -> Bool
isBar (Bar _) = True
isBar _       = False
```

Comment: An idiom: `isBar x = is [ () | Bar{} <- [x] ]` (where `is = not . null`).   Unfortunately it's a very noisy idiom.